# Newlines and special characters in HTML attributes

Tags: html

My questions are simple:

Is the following valid? If it is, would it break in some browsers?

```
<div data-text="Blah blah blah
More blah
And just a little extra blah to finish"> ... </div>
```

---

Which characters "must" be encoded in attribute values? I know `"` should be `&quot;`, but are any others required to be encoded?

Comment: How about HTML4? Are rules different there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the following valid?

It's a valid fragment of HTML5, yes.

> would it break in some browsers?

Unlikely.

> Which characters "must" be encoded in attribute values? I know `"` should be `&quot;`, but are any others required to be encoded?

That depends on whether the attribute value is double quoted, single quoted or unquoted.

For the double quoted form `"` must be replaced by its character reference, and `&` may need to be replaced by its character reference depending on the characters that follow it. See [attribute-value-double-quoted-state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28double-quoted%29-state)

For the single quoted form `'` must be replaced by its character reference, and `&` may need to be replaced by its character reference depending on the characters that follow it. See [attribute-value-single-quoted-state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28single-quoted%29-state)

For the unquoted form `TAB`, `LINEFEED`, `FORMFEED`, `SPACE`, `>` must be replaced by their character references, and `&` may need to be replaced by its character reference depending on the characters that follow it. See [attribute-value-unquoted-state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28unquoted%29-state)

Comment: There are more characters that must be encoded as part of [an unquoted attribute value](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values). For example, the ``` character should be encoded, else it will be invalid HTML5. The reason for this is that the ``` character can be used to break out of an unquoted attribute value in old IE versions. Here’s a tool that will tell you if a given attribute value is okay to use without quotes: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#foo%60bar

Comment: As for when `&` needs to be encoded, see http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML 5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#global-attributes)

There are different requirements for different attributes so there isn't one answer.
For instance, title attributes allow lines feeds, but a class attribute is a space seperated line of string tokens.

For data elements though the spec says of the namespace:

> contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

Other than that, it doesn't make any distinctions.